# How to found a dist folder in trix

Tags: trix

Why can't I find the "dist" folder in trix.zip?

I was watching a tutorial about trix, and he had a dist folder, but after I downloaded trix from github, I cant find the dist folder. What should I do? If I have to download another version, please give me the link.